# Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

I have Wordpress on http://www.sunshinebabysitting.com/blog

With GEODIRECTORY installed using SuperMagPro as the theme.  I believe it is loading the Google Maps API more than once or something and I don't know how to fix it.

How do I get the black box with `x` to go away. I inspected the page and found this:

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.0.0
on_document_load.js?ver=1.6.3:298 Google Maps API Loaded :)
ping:1 Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.
util.js:211 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with Google maps. The warning from Google would not cause the overlay and x to appear.

There seems to be an issue with the GeoDirectory plugin.

You might contact the developers of the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/geodirectory/
https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/geodirectory

Comment: NO ONE AT THE WORDPRESS PLUGIN WEBSITE is answering my concern!

Answer (score 0):

Your site could be hacked or have some bad code.
It seems that when you click anything that popup blocks the site.
In the source code, there is a swipebox div that loads on click of anything.

I would try disabling all the plugins and then activate them on at a time to see which one is causing the issue.